# Is there a way to query a temporal table to see if any history exists?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, temporal-tables

My EF Core 6 application is using SQL Temporal tables.

I have an existing query that returns a number of rows based on a filter:

```
       var results = Context.MyTable
            .Where(cn => cn.Name == "Fred")
            .Skip(5)
            .Take(10)
            .Select(x=>new { FirstName = x=>x.Name, Dob = x=>x.Dob });
```

What I want to do, is add a property in the response that shows if there is any history for each row in the query, so I can return it to the UI, which will show paging controls for stepping through the history.

```
       var results = Context.MyTable
            .Where(cn => cn.Name == "Fred")
            .Skip(5)
            .Take(10)
            .Select(x=>new { FirstName = x=>x.Name, Dob = x=>x.Dob, HasHistory = x.???? });
```

Comment: Is the history where you skipped 5 items?

Comment: No, I want to return 5 items, but I want to know if any of those 5 had history.

Comment: Than you cannot skip.  I would change the Select to include index number so you can distinguish between the first 5 items and the rest using : .Select((x,i) =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```cs
var results = Context.MyTable
    .Where(cn => cn.Name == "Fred")
    .Skip(5)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(x => new 
    { 
        FirstName = x.Name, 
        Dob = x.Dob, 
        HasHistory = Context.MyTable.TemporalAll().Count(h => h.Id == x.Id) > 1
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @Svyastoslav.   You led me to the right answer: `.Select(x => new { x.Id, HasHistory = Context.CaseNotes.TemporalAll().Count(h => h.Id == x.Id) > 1 })`

Comment: Yes, it was my second solution. Never tried temporal tables  before.